# How can I update the path variable for R in Github's Atom?

Tags: r, atom-editor

I cannot find where the path variable for R in Atom is.

The specified path in the Atom package `ide-r` is set to R 3.6 but I'm still running on 3.4.4.
I checked r-languageserver and hydrogen.

How can I update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## edit: automagically

When installing [IRkernel](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel) you need to register the kernel with `IRkernel::installspec()`. `installspec`overrides the ir `kernel.json` file with the R version from which it is called.

If you want to have multiple R versions installed you can change the name in the function. On the other hand, you could simply add another kernel manually as described in the following section.

## old: manually

After 4 hours of search, I finally found the answer.
In my folder `C:\User\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\ir\` there is a file called `kernel.json`
This file runs the specific R version. 
The file looks now like this:

```
{
  "argv": ["C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.0/bin/R.exe", "--slave", "-e", "IRkernel::main()", "--args", "{connection_file}"],
  "display_name": "R",
  "language": "R"
}
```

The original version of that file had the relative path to the version 3.4.4.

After finding the responsible file to be in the folder of Jupyter I conclude that Jupyter calls R - which is unfortunately not surprising, because Hydrogen runs a Jupyter Notebook.